# Accessing data from previous rows in Mondo DB /Oracle style Lag operation for MongoDB

Tags: oracle, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In Oracle there exists the LAG analytics function which is used to access data from a previous rows.

Is there any straightforward way of achieving this same effect with MongoDB?

What I actually want to do is display the daily change in stock prices. So from the below input

```
 {
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-01",
     "price":97.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-02",
     "price":98.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-03",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    .
    .
    .      
}
```

I'd want to return something along the lines of

```
 {
   {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-01",
     "dailyChange":null                         
    },
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-02",
     "dailyChange":1.0                         
    },    
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-03",
     "dailyChange":1.0                         
    },
    .
    .
    .      
}
```

But to do this I need to access the row previous to the row I'm processing each time. It would be really nice to be able to do this using the aggregation framework if possible.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt.

UPDATE:

As suggested by below, storing this information down makes sense as the data is not changing. This would mean that every time new prices come in new daily change values would need to be created.

What would be the best method for doing this? A map reduce task would seem best but it's not clear to me how this would be structured.

Comment: Why not store the value when you set the data? It would seem unnecessarily expensive to use the aggregation framework to perform that work every time since the result never changes (if it's even practical to do).

Comment: Thanks, I definitely will. So I suppose the question is what's the best way of generating this information. A map reduce task would suffice I suppose.

Comment: You can easily query for "yesterday's" data, can't you? if the fails to find a value, Can't you just query for the most recent entry for a given stock, sorted and limited to just the first?